# Strange message declaring a Pointer[void] in a NativeCall perl6 module

Tags: raku, nativecall

These snippets of code may seem odd, it's because I started with my original code and cut off pieces until I arrived to the minimal set of instructions that reproduced the error. So bear with the apparent uselessness.
There are two perl6 modules, one `use`s the other one, and a program.
This is the first module:

```
unit class test1;

use NativeCall;
use test2;

method test
{
  my Pointer[void] $dummy .= new;
}
```

The second module is included by the first one, but no part of it is actually used:

```
unit module test2;

use NativeCall;

class A is repr('CStruct') is export {
  has Pointer[void] $.wrongdoer;
  has int32 $.a;
}
```

The program creates a test1 object and calls the test method:

```
use lib '.';
use test1;

my test1 $t .= new;
$t.test;
```

This program outputs an error, apparently caused by the assignment in the class test1's method test:

```
Type check failed in assignment to $dummy; expected NativeCall::Types::Pointer[NativeCall::Types::void] but got NativeCall::Types::Pointer[NativeCall::Types::void].new(0)
```

If I comment out the `$.wrongdoer` in the second class, the program executes with no error.
I'm running rakudo 2018.06.
Is this a bug in the NativeCall module or something else I fail to see?

Comment: Declaring `test1` and using it by itself also works... Declaring A and instantiating it causes no problem either, either in 2018.03 or 2018.06. Can you please try and check again?

Comment: If you remove the `[void]` it doesn't generate that error.

Comment: I think this has been fixed. (A 2022 Rakudo doesn't generate an error.)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Brad Gilbert, removing the `[void]` stops the spooky action at a distance.

Comment: I think this has been fixed. (A 2022 Rakudo doesn't generate an error.)